# OpenCart Version Control How to Ignore Templates/Themes/Plugins

Tags: git, version-control, opencart

I'm trying to set up a version controlled codebase for OpenCart as well as separately version controlled OC templates, themes and plugins.

---

**WordPress analogue**

I've done something similar with WordPress by placing the following in my .gitignore file

```
/public_html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/**/*
!/public_html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/index.php

/public_html/wordpress/wp-content/themes/**/*
!/public_html/wordpress/wp-content/themes/index.php
```

Which tells the WP repo not to keep track of anything in the plugins/themes folders except for index.php.

Then I can drop my plugin into the plugins folder and `git status` returns no changes. When I update my WP code base, I can just pull it in.

---

I would like to have a similar workflow with OpenCart, however it gets a little bit more interesting with how spread out all the OC theme files can get.

**Option 1.**
I'm wondering about using same approach of setting up my OC .gitignore to exclude everything except core files. Essentially

```
#For every directory that a theme/template/plugin file might land
/path/to/dir1/**/*
!/path/to/dir1/corefile1
!/path/to/dir1/coredir1/**/*
...
!/path/to/dir1/corefileX
!/path/to/dir1/coredirY/**/*
...
/path/to/dirZ/**/*
!/path/to/dirZ/corefile1
!/path/to/dirZ/coredir1/**/*
...
!/path/to/dirZ/corefileM
!/path/to/dirZ/coredirN/**/*
```

That seems to me like it could get out of hand though. Are there a finite number of locations that a new theme/template/plugin would place files? Is this system going to break down the moment I install a weird plugin that drops files outside of the normal locations? I don't want my .gitignore turning into something where I have to explicitly include every core OC file.

**Option 2.**
Create my .gitignore file in a way that I explicitly ignore every file that is added as part of a theme/file/plugin. This method seems very tedious as well. Since I would have to add this to the ignore file my core OC repository, every OC project would have all the ignore rules for every other project.

**Option 3.**
Just to abandon this method altogether. In which case, whenever I want to update the OC core (for instance go from v2.2 to v2.3) I'll just have to stash/pop all the extras that I've installed.

---

Option 1 is what I'm leaning toward but rather than just go through with it, I was hoping someone with more OC plugin experience could let me know how feasible it is.

I would also be interested in hearing any other solutions.

---

---

Update:

Based on the information provided by Lucas I started taking a look at what I can do with my Option 1 strategy. I gave up on that almost immediately.

As a start I created the following rules for language files.

```
# Ignore everything in the language folder
/uploads/catalog/language/**/*
# Except default language
!/uploads/catalog/language/en-gb/**/*
```

The problem I immediately ran into is that if I install a module that adds a en-gb language file it ends up included in this repository. So this puts me in the same situation again where I have to decide whether I should whether to explicitly ignore the module file, or explicitly include every core en-gb file.

If I have to explicitly include all files, it's entirely possible that an OC core upgrade comes along with a new file, and I never know it exists and so I never get it under version control, and it doesn't ship to my new sites. This could be dealt with by doing a file system comparison between my current OC and new OC whenever I upgrade, and adding any new files to the .gitignore. This wouldn't happen often but it's still pretty ugly IMO.

---

The Option 2 idea is starting to feel a bit cleaner. I don't mind specifically ignoring files for any modules I add. The real issue is when I tweak a file for a specific website. This seems like something that would often happen, not many people are entirely happen with themes exactly as downloaded.

I really don't want to have lines like.

```
# Ignore files belonging to mywebsite.com
/upload/catalog/view/theme/mywebsite.com/**/*
```

When there will only ever be one OC instance that uses those files.

Answer (score 1):

Themes are pretty easy to ignore - they reside in /catalog/view/theme/*

OC defaults to serving pieces from default/ if the new theme doesn't have an equivalent file and therefore shouldn't be touched.

Default language is /catalog/language/en-gb/*, any other would have had to have been intentionally added.

Lots of modules have files added in 6(!) different places:

```
/admin/controller/module/
/admin/model/module/
/admin/view/theme/default/module/

/catalog/controller/module/
/catalog/model/module/
/catalog/view/theme/default/module/
```

Some modules might add new language files as well.

And some modules create new tables in the database, while others might just add new columns to existing tables.

It's kind of a mess, honestly.

It might be worth it to clone a fresh install of the current OC install for the version you're using git projet, copy your existing install over it to see what changes it makes, just as a starting point.

Comment: This is more or less as I suspected. I know many modules also use VQMods, is there a directory(or directories) where those files normally end up?

Comment: All VQMOD's end up in /vqmod/xml/

They don't change any of the core files, they make new, changed copies, that get stored in /vqmod/vqcache/